# Не видит переменную

Tags: python-3.x

Только познакомился с программированием для школьного проекта и выдает такую ошибку: NameError: name 'testTmp' is not defined
Сам код:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Солнечная система')
mainmenu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=mainmenu)
root.geometry('300x300')

canvas = Canvas(root, width = 300, height= 300, bg = 'lightgrey')
canvas.pack()

def testGet():
    print(testTmp.get())

def testSetting():
    setting = tk.Tk()
    setting.title('Настройки')
    setting.geometry('300x300')
    cavnassetting = Canvas(setting, width = 1020, height= 650, bg = 'lightgrey')
    cavnassetting.pack()

    global testTmp_entry

    testTmp_entry = tk.Entry(setting, bg = 'gray', bd = 5 )
    testTmp_entry.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.25)

    create = Button(setting, text=".get()", command=testGet)
    create.place(relx=0.25, rely=0.35, width = 150)

mainmenu.add_command(label='Настройки', command=testSetting)

root.mainloop()
```

И если вам не составит труда объясните почему компилятор не видит эту переменную

Comment: В функции `testGet` Вы обращаетесь к `testTmp`, но такого имени нет, оно нигде не определено, о чём Вам и сообщает `Python`.

Comment: замените `print(testTmp.get())` на `print(testTmp_entry.get())`

Answer (score 1):

Потому что это интерпретатор)

На самом деле, переменная testTmp нигде не объявлена, что и вызывает исключение.